# How to get the idRetainer in the listRetainerPaymentUnit?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a Angualr JS application and i try to get Id on my JSON im new with JSON objects.

> {{detAgent[queryFilter][0][listRetainerPaymentUnit][0]}}

```html
{
 "queryFilter": [{
  "objPolicyData": {"idAssign": "219","idPromotoria": "JA",
        "listStatusPolicy": [{"policyStatusCode": "V"}],
        "collectionType": {"DxN": true},
        "listRetainerPaymentUnit": [{"idRetainer": "100","nameRetainer": "RETAINER","idPaymentUnit": "109","namePaymentUnit": "PAYMEMT UNIT"}],
        "listFederalEntity": [{"idFederalEntity": "MEX","nameFederalEntity": "CDMX"}],
        "listZipCode": ""
  },
  "policyDataInfo": {
   "policyNumber": "100",
   "sizeOfFullPolicyDataObject": 480,
   "unitSizeFullPolicyDataObject": "MB"
  }
 }]
}
```

I expect to obtain the data with a tag **Id**

Comment: You forgot about the key `objPolicyData` after the first `[0]`. `detAgent[queryFilter][0][objPolicyData][listRetainerPaymentUnit][0]`. Also, you have in your `$scope` an object called `detAgent` with this value, right? Can you eventually show us more of your code? (edit your code with a jsfiddle).

Comment: Thanks Adi yeah i forgot that Object  this is the link with the code i need to show the parameters of my JSON but im new in this https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tOKURtmbkO

Comment: In your fiddle, you are making a request to a local server, can't really be tested.

Comment: I use eclipse and running on my local server  actually the request is ref to a mock service but that can change if you ad  the json route in the http.get

Comment: I'm not really sure how you get the object detAgent into the controller, because that's the place it needs to be. If it is a simple JSON, you can make `$scope.detAgent = JSON.parse(yourResponseFromServer)` and it should work. You can test it first with a simple `{{ detAgent }}` in your HTML, something must show up.

Comment: detAgent its an variable that call in agentsDetailList in the ng-repeat directive when i prove it that detAgent it´s bring to me the complete Json

Comment: it´s show the json https://ibb.co/2Wnnp6v

Answer (score 1):

Resolve i remove the ng-repeat directive in the html and to get the id I only pass the variable

```
<div class="col-3 text-left"><label>Id {{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].objPolicyData.idAssign}}</label></div>
```